# Mule - JSON to XML - Unbound prefix

Tags: json, xml, mule, prefix, transformer-model

With my `mule flow` I get a `JSON` message and I use a `JSON to XML transformer` to send the XML to a Web Service.

`HTTP` => `JSON to XML` => `WS Consumer`

The XML needs a prefix "**int:**" :

```
<int:contact>Name</int:contact>
```

And the JSON format is like this:

```
{  
   "Modify":{  
      "int:contact":"Name"
   }
}
```

The `JSON to XML transformer` return an error:

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unbound prefix: int

How can I pass the prefix?

Comment: A prefix and a colon like that in XML represents an "XML namespace". If you are not using namespaces, you *cannot* use `:` in your tag names; if you are using namespaces, you need to assign a namespace (identified by a URI) to that prefix at the top of your document (e.g. `xmlns:int="http://example.org/myXMLNamespace"`).

Comment: Thanks. I need to use namespaces. Where should I add that namespace URI in the mule flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Namespace manager.

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="int" uri="http://int.com"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Comment: But.. Where should I add that?

Comment: in xml document..before flow start